# getParameterValues sometimes return null from hidden input

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a website and I used form inside .jsp file when the user submit the form the action goes to servlet which insert data into database. sometimes it works fine without any problem and sometimes even the user submitted the form nothing inserted in the database and throws NullPointerException in line 154.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for 
servlet [NewServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.example.test.NewServlet.processRequest(NewServlet.java:154)
```

index.jsp

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="subjects1">
SELECT * FROM glf2 ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 1
</sql:query>
<c:set var="comments_m1" value="${subjects1.rows[0]}"/>
${comments_m1.comment_message} 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="subjects2">
SELECT * FROM egy ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 1
</sql:query>
<c:set var="comments_m2" value="${subjects2.rows[0]}"/>
${comments_m2.comment_message} 
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="com" value="${comments_m1.comment_message}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="com" value="${comments_m2.comment_message}"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">  
</form>
```

the comment message selected from database and shown in the screen and the user need to select some options, then the comment message and the user options send to servelt to be inserted into database table.

newservlet.java acording to the log file the problem in getParametersValues

```
try (PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter()) {
comment1= req.getParameterValues("com");
for(int z=0; z<comment1.length;z++)
comment[z] = new String(comment1[z].getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```

Any one could advice me please how to solve the problem.

Comment: Is the line 154 in NewServlet.java `comment1= req.getParameterValues("com");`?

Comment: It is the next line for(int z=0; z<comment1.length;z++)

Comment: @fgo any advice could help me.

Comment: @BalusC any advice please.

Comment: Give the name of hidden field as **com[]** then you get the value in proper manner

Comment: Thank you, I am trying now to see, I hope it solve the problem.

Comment: @shivam I tried still throws NullPointerException, I think the problem in the related to the life of the input itself.

Comment: @Areej this code is working for me plz check

String [] comment1= request.getParameterValues("com");
  String comment[] = new String [2]; 
  for(int z=0; z<comment1.length;z++)
   comment[z] = new String(comment1[z].getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");

Comment: @shivam I did like this exactly and It works in my laptop with glassfish server but when I launched the war file to my website I got NullPointerException sometimes and nothing inserted in the database but sometimes no any problem, so suppose 5 clients submitted the 5 forms 3 forms inserted into database and two not inserted and throw this exception.

Comment: @Areej At a time of submission of form plz change all hidden control to text using any of the scripting language, because of some time in glassfish server many time it didnt consider hidden control as input control so if you did this you can got the solution.

Comment: Thank you, but I noticed that also the radio buttons which are not hidden send null instead of the value selected. I think the problem related to scope I tried to use ${scoperequest[radiobuttonvalue]} but when I check the page source It shows empty in the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries aren't necessarily return a record with `comment_message` is not null.

So, for example, you may have to add a null check.

```
if (comment1 != null) {
    for (int z=0; z<comment1.length;z++)
    comment[z] = new String(comment1[z].getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"); 
}
```

Comment: No it must return record and this record shown to the user on the screen before he submit the form in the JSP.

Comment: Did you check hidden values of the page source by right click on the page before submitting?

Comment: No, actually I just found that the client enter the website and submit the form but nothing inserted into the database and when I checked with the hosting they show me this error which is happen sometimes. Is it something related to the scope, is it related to the the number of client who submit the form in same time.!!

Comment: I just tried to see the source there are values which are the result of the select statement no any null.

Answer (score -1):

Put a check for Null from the value of the parameter before insertion,

```
boolean comBool = comment1.equals("") || comment1.length<0 ;
if(!comBool){
       //Do the insertion into database
}else{
//the value from entered field is null
}
```

This will solve your NullPointerException

Comment: No, it must contains a value not null.

Comment: So you want a value which is not null also?

Comment: the value actually not null because it shown in the screen as text not null.

Comment: did you tried `req.getParameter("com");` The error over `for(int z=0; z<comment1.length;z++)` occured  only because the comment1 is null.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do,but for temporary storage of value,you can use session and call the session for value using the attribute name .

Comment: no I can't use req.getParameter because they are 15 values with same name so I need to get it in array of String using req.getParameterValues. I feel the problem with the scope (request or session) but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Actually I created a form contains 15 sentences selected randomly from the database which are saved in hidden input ("com") and after the user see the sentences and decide these sentences written in which dialects bt select the dialects from radio buttons then submit the form to the servlet to insert the sentences and the user selected (radio button values) to database, and it works sometimes and sometimes show me NullPointer error!!

Comment: Are these 15 values are setting up into the hidden input tag? If so,then you can use to call the req.paraValue from only one input tag,not from all the the hidden input tags.Use javascript or jquery for this

Comment: yes they setting into hidden input as I wrote in the question I gave example for 2 just.  and I used req.getParameter("com"); only one to get the 15 value and save it in commnt1 array of String.

Answer (score -1):

You are actually using same name for both the input tag in form, because of that the compiler might be getting confused about which value to get.

You should check naming both input tags different. It should work.

Comment: I used same name to get all values as array of string using getPramaterValues, and I tried to rename each input with different name then get each one using getParameter then store it in array but still it throws NullPointerException in this comment[z] = new String(comment1[z].getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"); .